# How would I compare jumbled words to dictionary words in two files using HashMaps in Java?

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

So I constructed some simple code to compare two text files. One with a jumbled list of words that are supposed to match up to words in the dictionary file. Basically finding which jumbled words match to their dictionary word. Some words have a few jumbled words that match to them, some don't have any matches. I'm looking to change this code to be much simpler, using HashMaps to make the program simpler and faster, but I'm not very good with HashMaps at all and could use the help.

Here is the code I currently have for the non-hashmap version if it helps:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project6
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        if (args.length < 2 ) die( "Must give name of two input files on cmd line." );

        BufferedReader dFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[0] ) );
        BufferedReader jFile = new BufferedReader( new FileReader( args[1] ) );

        ArrayList<String> jWordList= new ArrayList<String>();  
        ArrayList<String> dWordList= new ArrayList<String>();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (dFile.ready())
        {
             String word = dFile.readLine();
             dWordList.add( word );
        }
        dFile.close();

        while (jFile.ready())
        {
             String word = jFile.readLine();
             jWordList.add( word );
        }
        jFile.close();

        Collections.sort( dWordList );
        Collections.sort( jWordList );

        String[] dArray = dWordList.toArray(new String[dWordList.size()]);
        String[] jArray = jWordList.toArray(new String[jWordList.size()]);

        dArray = canonArray( dArray );
        jArray = canonArray( jArray );

        for(int i = 0 ; i < jWordList.size() ; i++)
        {
            String jWord = jArray[i];
            System.out.print(jWordList.get(i) + " ");
            for(int c = 0 ; c < dWordList.size() ; c++)
            {
                String dWord = dArray[c];
                if(jWord.equals(dWord))
                {
                    System.out.print(dWordList.get(c) + " ");
                }

            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
        long ms = endTime-startTime;
        System.out.println("Elapsed time in seconds: " + ms/1000.0 + "\n"); // 1 ms is a 1,000th of a second
    } 

    private static void die( String errmsg )
    {
                System.out.println( "\nFATAL ERROR: " + errmsg + "\n" );
                System.exit(0);
    }
    private static String toCanonical( String word )
    { 
        char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(charArray);
        String charNewString = new String(charArray);
        return charNewString;
    }
    private static String[] canonArray( String[] Arr )
    {
        String[] newArr = new String[Arr.length];
        for(int i = 0 ; i < Arr.length ; i++)
        {
            String temp = toCanonical(Arr[i]);
            newArr[i] = temp;

        }
        return newArr;
    }
}
```

It produces the following output, which I would like to keep exactly the same (minus the print of elapsed time):

[image: output]

Comment: A HashSet is what you want.  You can just shove all of the dictionary words in there and call the contains method. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: @NoivernEvo - does it have to be HashMaps? because in my opinion, a BinarySearchTree would be much more suitable for this task.

Comment: Yup, has to be HashMaps.

Comment: What's the purpose of your map? Do you wish to link your jumbled word to it's canonical form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to define a HashMap such that the key's hash and equals method will come out the same regardless of the order and case of the string's characters. The following takes a String and converts it to lowercase and sorts the characters.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project6 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) die("Must give name of two input files on cmd line.");

        BufferedReader dFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        BufferedReader jFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[1]));

        HashMap<String, List<String>> dWordMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        while (dFile.ready()) {
            String word = dFile.readLine();
            if (word == null) break;

            addWord(word, dWordMap);
        }
        dFile.close();

        while (jFile.ready()) {
            String jWord = jFile.readLine();
            if (jWord == null) break;

            List<String> dWords = dWordMap.get(createKey(jWord));

            if (dWords != null) {
                System.out.println(jWord + " " + dWords);
            }
        }
        jFile.close();

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long ms = endTime - startTime;
        System.out.println("Elapsed time in seconds: " + ms / 1000.0 + "\n");
    }

    private static void die(String errmsg) {
        System.out.println("\nFATAL ERROR: " + errmsg + "\n");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    private static String createKey(String word) {
        char[] chword = word.toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(chword);

        return new String(chword);
    }

    private static void addWord(String word, Map<String, List<String>> map) {
        String key = createKey(word);

        List<String> list = map.get(key);
        if(list==null) {
            list = new ArrayList<String>();
            map.put(key, list);
        }

        list.add(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you prefer to retain the order, use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a class file addon. Everything has to happen within one file.

Comment: @NoivernEvo  Seems odd, but okay... write a method that converts a string to an all lowercase with sorted characters and use that as the key.  Don't use a char[] because the getHash method will not return the same value for different instances.

Comment: @NoivernEvo Answer updated to not use any classes other than those defined by the Java API.